# cmake foreach loop not running

Tags: c++, cmake

I have following code block in cmake:-

```
foreach(X IN LISTS "${DBSCHEMA}/dbschema.cpp;${DBSCHEMA}/dbschema.hpp")
    message("-----------setting ${X} --------------")
    set_property(SOURCE ${X} PROPERTY SKIP_AUTOMOC ON)
    set_property(SOURCE ${X} PROPERTY SKIP_AUTOUIC ON)
endforeach()
```

but when I run cmake I don't see anyline like

```
message("-----------setting ${X} --------------")
```

and properties are not set

but following like

```
message("list = ${DBSCHEMA}/dbschema.cpp;${DBSCHEMA}/dbschema.hpp")
```

does give me output like this:-

```
/some/very/long/path/dbschema.cpp;/some/very/long/path/dbschema.hpp
```

Comment: did you try with `IN ITEMS` ? which version of cmake did you use ?

Comment: @Mizux its CMake version 3.16.5. Also, I solved the problem by removing  `IN LIST `

Answer (score 2):

I needed to remove `IN LIST` words:-

```
foreach(X ${DBSCHEMA}/dbschema.cpp ${DBSCHEMA}/dbschema.hpp)
    set_property(SOURCE ${X} PROPERTY SKIP_AUTOMOC ON)
    set_property(SOURCE ${X} PROPERTY SKIP_AUTOUIC ON)
endforeach()
```